# Joining 2 datasets and creating new rows where matches are found

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets that I would like to join using R -

Dataset 1

```
    ID Name Date Price
    1    A   2011 $100
    2    B   2012 $200
    3    C   2013 $300
```

Dataset 2

```
    ID Date Price
    1  2012 $100
    1  2013 $200
    3  2014 $300
```

Using `left-join()` in `dplyr` by ID I'd end up with this

```
    ID Name Date.x Price.x Date.y Price.y
    1   A   2011    $100   2012   $100
    1   A   2011    $100   2013   $200
    2   B   2012    $200
    3   C   2013    $300   2014   $300
```

What I would however like to have as a final product is this

```
    ID Name Date Price
    1  A     2011 $100
    1  A     2012 $100
    1  A     2013 $200
    2  B     2012 $200
    3  C     2013 $300
    3  C     2014 $300
```

i.e instead of merging to the existing row, I'd like to create a new row when a match is found and duplicate the existing information that won't change (ID and Name) and alter the Date and Price column where necessary. Any ideas as to an efficient way to do this on a large dataset?

Comment: do you mean `left_join` ? Did you join on `Date` ? your output table does not appear to reflect this. `left_join(df1, df2, by="Date")`

Comment: Looks a lot like `rbind`.

Comment: Use `df2$Name <- LETTERS[df2$ID]` before the `rbind` to get the proper names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked about the efficient way, so I'll introduce data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)
setDT(DF2)

# structure your data so ID attributes are only in an ID table
idDT = DF1[, .(ID, Name)]
DF1[, Name := NULL]

# stack data
DT = rbind(DF1, DF2)

# grab ID attributes if you really need them
DT[idDT, on="ID", Name := i.Name]
```

which gives

```
   ID Date Price Name
1:  1 2011  $100    A
2:  2 2012  $200    B
3:  3 2013  $300    C
4:  1 2012  $100    A
5:  1 2013  $200    A
6:  3 2014  $300    C
```

`rbind` for data.tables is pretty fast. I wouldn't really expect efficiency to be a big issue when just binding two tables, though.

Regarding spinning off the ID attribute, Name, it matches the recommendations of the dplyr package author, who refers to it as [making data tidy](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10).

Answer (score 4):

This is a slight variation of @Frank's answer. The main issue is that your 2nd table doesn't have a `Name` column. This can be obtained quite efficiently using *data.table*'s update while join approach..

```
require(data.table)
dt2[dt1, Name := i.Name, on = "ID"] # by reference, no need to assign the result back
```

Now that there's a `Name` column, we can simply `rbind` the result.

```
ans = rbind(dt1, if (anyNA(dt2$Name)) na.omit(dt2, by="Name") else dt2)
```

If necessary, *reorder* the result *by reference* using `setorder()`:

```
setorder(ans, ID, Name) # by reference, no need to assign the result back
#    ID Name Date Price
# 1:  1    A 2011  $100
# 2:  1    A 2012  $100
# 3:  1    A 2013  $200
# 4:  2    B 2012  $200
# 5:  3    C 2013  $300
# 6:  3    C 2014  $300
```

`:=` operator and `set*` functions in *data.table* modify the input object by reference.

---

```
dt1 = fread('ID Name   Date Price
              1    A   2011  $100
              2    B   2012  $200
              3    C   2013  $300')

dt2 = fread('ID  Date Price
              1  2012  $100
              1  2013  $200
              3  2014  $300')
```

Comment: If there is no matches in ID, will the rbind work here?

Comment: for example ID in dt2, all have ID = 4

Comment: @Sathish, thanks. I think the edit handles such cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID=1:3,
  Name=c("A","B","C"),
  Date=c(2011,2012,2013),
  Price=c(100,200,300)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  ID=c(1,1,3),
  Date=c(2012,2013,2014),
  Price=c(100,200,300)
)
```

`left_join` won't get you that desired output. You can use `full_join`.

```
merged <- full_join(df1, df2, by=c("Date","ID"))
```

Here's a way to get to the output you want with `melt` from the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
merged <- melt(merged, id.vars=c("ID","Name","Date"))
```

Then:

```
> merged[na.omit(merged$Name), -4] #remove NAs and column from melt
    ID Name Date value
1    1    A 2011   100
2    2    B 2012   200
3    3    C 2013   300
1.1  1    A 2011   100
2.1  2    B 2012   200
3.1  3    C 2013   300
```

Answer (score 1):

Inner join with `nomatch = 0`. For example, if all ID in dataset2 is 4, inner join will not spit NA to non-matching IDs. If you remove `nomatch = 0`, then `NA`s will be produced.

**EDIT:** added rbindlist wrapper as per @Arun's suggestion

```
library("data.table")
rbindlist(list(df1, 
               setDT(df1)[i = df2, 
                          j = .(ID, Name, Date = i.Date, Price = i.Price),
                          on = .(ID), 
                          nomatch = 0]))
```

**Output:**

```
   ID Name Date Price
1:  1    A 2011  $100
2:  2    B 2012  $200
3:  3    C 2013  $300
4:  1    A 2012  $100
5:  1    A 2013  $200
6:  3    C 2014  $300
```

Comment: You can use `rbindlist()` -- it takes list as input.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the efficient ways to do that is to use two steps merge.

```
# create Dataset 1
ID <- 1:3
Name <- c("A", "B", "C")
Date <- 2011:2013
Price <- c("$100", "$200", "$300")
dataset1 <- data.frame(ID, Name, Date, Price)

# Create Dataset 2
ID <- c(1,1,3)
Date <- 2012:2014
Price <- c("$100", "$200", "$300")
dataset2 <- data.frame(ID, Date, Price)
```

Assign missing "Name" values to Dataset 2 by using `merge` function in {base} package

```
dataset2 <- merge(dataset1[c("ID", "Name")], dataset2)
```

Merge datasets

```
merge(dataset1, dataset2, all = T)
```

Which gives:

```
   ID Name Date Price
1  1    A 2011  $100
2  1    A 2012  $100
3  1    A 2013  $200
4  2    B 2012  $200
5  3    C 2013  $300
6  3    C 2014  $300
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Plyr to join and get the names for the second DF and rbind to union the rows.

```
library(plyr)

## Add the name column to df2 and get rid of unwanted columns
df3 <- join(df2,df1,by = "ID")
df3[,6] <- NULL
df3[,5] <- NULL

combined <- rbind(df1,df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 > dsa
   ID Name Date Price
 1  1    A 2011  $100
 2  2    B 2012  $200
 3  3    C 2013  $300

 >dsb
  ID Date Price
 1  1 2012  $100
 2  1 2013  $200
 3  3 2014  $300

 >dsb$Name <- NA

 >dsr <- rbind(dsa,dsb)
 >dsr$Name <- dsa$Name[match(dsr$ID,dsa$ID)]
 >dsr

   ID Name Date Price
 1  1    A 2011  $100
 2  2    B 2012  $200
 3  3    C 2013  $300
 4  1    A 2012  $100
 5  1    A 2013  $200
 6  3    C 2014  $300
```

I am newbie to R. Couldn't make use of full potential of R for best efficiency. But, this does the job.